# Streaming Windows Media Center recorded TV across the internet

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, video-streaming

I'm looking for some expert opinions on streaming recorded TV from Windows Media Center over the internet.  I would prefer that the file being streamed is converted to a smaller size (i.e., resize the video) in some way so that my slow upload pipe can handle it.  I do record a lot of HD content, so this type of compression is a must.

Thanks!

Comment: Videos are *already* compressed.

Comment: @Sathya - I redefined what I mean by compression...can you remove your downvote?

Comment: I was not the one who put in the downvote @TReddy

Comment: @Sathya - sorry about that comment...I don't know who did it then...

Comment: I shall compensate with an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

As you're working with Microsoft products already then [Microsoft Expression Encoder 4](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/Default.aspx#ProductInfo) is probably what you're looking for.

Expression is the replacement for Windows Media Encoder

> Expression Encoder imports and encodes
>   video files, produces live webcasts,
>   enhances media with watermarks and
>   advertising, and publishes with
>   Silverlight.

Comment: thanks for the answer...but there has to be something free out there that I can do?

Comment: Expression 4 is free.  Purple "download now" button in the bottom left of that link's page, or go here instead: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5c3c5f97-678c-4c99-a7fc-f84f320c626f&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

I used [tversity](http://tversity.com/) two years ago to do the same. Also it supports multiple types of clients and it auto re-compresses content so it's optimized for each one

Answer (score 0):

I use [Remote Potato](http://www.remotepotato.com/) which not only streams your recorded TV through your web browser but also allows you to access your EPG and manage your recordings remotely.